# Does the ADT plugin automatically create an ant build file?

Tags: xml, android, ant, build, adt

I created an Android project a few months ago and now have to automate the build process with Hudson. The Android dev guide mentions a build.xml file that gets created when you generate a project (http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html) but I dont see one in my project. Will I have to create this by hand or can I run a command to generate it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ADT plugin doesn't generate an Ant file.

The `android` command will generate an Ant file when you create a new project from the command line by calling `android create project`.  You could create an example project and copy the `build.xml`, `build.properties` and `local.properties` files from that directory.

Alternatively, you can just copy the `build.xml` template directly from `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib/build.template` then just change the project name.

Then just create a `build.properties` file — it's where you place any Ant property overrides.
Also you need a `local.properties` file, but don't check that into source control — this is where you specify your `$ANDROID_HOME` directory by setting the `sdk.dir` property.

Comment: Silly question. If `local.properties` isn’t in source control, what are you supposed to do when you check out the project?

Comment: Do I *need* a build.properties file? I dont know - can you give me an example of where I would need it? Basically this project was created using the ADT plugin but now I need to automate the build in Hudson, so I need to figure out how to get it to build over there.

Comment: No, by default it's empty when the `android` tool creates it (just with a bunch of comments demonstrating how you could use that file).

Answer (score 10):

The following will generate a build.xml file as well as a local.properties file if one does not exist in your project.

`android update project --path <path to your project directory>`

Answer (score 3):

You can use these steps below:

- Open command line
- Go to: `<path/to/android sdk/tools>`
- Run: `$ android update project --path /path/to/my-project` => it will generate `build.xml` and `local.properties`
- Create file: `ant.properties` with two line below

  ```
  key.store=path/to/keystore
  key.alias=alias name
  ```
- Open `build.xml` and rename project name if need
- Run as `ant build` (debug, release, etc...)