# Android custom build using Ant

Tags: android, ant, build

These 4 files (build.xml, local.properties, projects.properties, proguard.cfg) are auto-generated when running:

> android update project --name TestApp --target 10 -p .
>
> Updated project.properties
>
> Updated local.properties
>
> Added file ./build.xml
>
> Updated file ./proguard.cfg

But I want the "auto-gen" build.xml to also include the following "pre-compile" code as well, is there a way to do that? Is there some "include" file or "template" file which can include that?

```
  <target name="config">

  <property name="config-target-path" value="${source.dir}/com/androidengineer/antbuild"/>

  <!-- Copy the configuration file, replacing tokens in the file. -->
  <copy file="config/Config.java" todir="${config-target-path}"
        overwrite="true" encoding="utf-8">
   <filterset>
    <filter token="CONFIG.LOGGING" value="${config.logging}"/>
   </filterset>
  </copy>

 </target>
```

Comment: Try to paste that code into your build.xml and then modify the "compile" target (it may be another name) like <target name="compile" depends="config"> ...

Comment: Hi, 
What I mean is "build.xml" is auto-generated when running "android update". I can't paste that code in there.  That's my problem and want to know if I can paste that code somewhere else but still able to get included when "android update" runs.

Comment: Will the build.xml run right after it is generated?

Comment: It can be delay, but yes, now it is run right after it is generated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `build.xml` as generated by the `android` tool (at least when using Android SDK r20) contains this piece of code:

```
<!--
    Import per project custom build rules if present at the root of the project.
    This is the place to put custom intermediary targets such as:
        -pre-build
        -pre-compile
        -post-compile (This is typically used for code obfuscation.
                       Compiled code location: ${out.classes.absolute.dir}
                       If this is not done in place, override ${out.dex.input.absolute.dir})
        -post-package
        -post-build
        -pre-clean
-->
<import file="custom_rules.xml" optional="true" />
```

So what I do to create additional targets or customize existing targets is to create a `custom_rules.xml` file with these new targets. Note that in my tests the targets needed to be nested in a `<project>` tag, so simply copy the first two lines of your generated `build.xml` to `custom_rules.xml`, and don't forget about the closing `</project>` tag in the end. As `custom_rules.xml` will not be overwritten by `android update` your changes will be persistent and can be checked into your SCM tool of choice.

Comment: Yup, it seems like they had fix it in the new SDK release.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can check the answer to this question:

[Does the ADT plugin automatically create an ant build file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464725/does-the-adt-plugin-automatically-create-an-ant-build-file)

in the answer there is a paragraph saying...

> Alternatively, you can just copy the build.xml template directly from $ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib/build.template then just change the project name.

Modify this file and run the commands to see if it works.

**Update**

Also check "Customizing the build" of this article: http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html

Comment: Thanks! But this does not work as I always run "android update project" at each time it builds which always generated a new "build.xml" and replace the existing one.

I'm looking for a solution to that.

Comment: Then I don't know why it doesn't work. Since there is a build.xml template, I think it should generate a new build.xml from the template each time you run "android update project", but it seems that is doesn't... Sorry for that.

Comment: Hi coolcfan, thanks for your ansewr, but I don't think you understand my problem here. 

I can make changes to the template, but that would be affecting all of my "other" projects as they are using the same SDK. I only want the customized changed for this particular project for this particular build. 


`So here is my situation:`
`1. Copy $ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib/build.template to build.xml`
`2. Modify the build.xml`
`3. Run "android update project"`
`4. "android update" generate a new build.xml which now replaced my copy of modified build.xml`

Comment: A stupid way is to write a script which overwrites the build-template at the start of your building process, then runs the commands, and then, whether the build succeeds or not, restore the original build-template in the end......

Comment: Thanks coolcfan, that's what I originally think about. I was just curious to know if there's a better solution for this like a way to have "android update project" to include some customized build.xml content when generating it..

Comment: Since you have more than one projects... Maybe there isn't. Does "android update project" has the ability to let you specify a build.xml template as a parameter or in a properties file? If not... Then the "stupid" way has to be the choice :P

Answer (score 1):

In `build.xml` itself, it tells you how to do this. See the following comment from the file:

```
<!--

    ***********************
    ****** IMPORTANT ******
    ***********************
    In all cases you must update the value of version-tag below to read 'custom' instead of an integer,
    in order to avoid having your file be overridden by tools such as "android update project"
-->
<!-- version-tag: 1 -->
```

Comment: I tried, and it didn't work :-(
But it could because a bug I had in my Android SDK. I will try again with the new update.