# Android project with Guava hitting the limit

Tags: android, proguard, guava, android-gradle-plugin, android-guava

I am using Guava in a Android project. I am hitting the 65k method limit which fails the gradle build. I found that this could be resolved by using proguard. I run Proguard on release build and it works fine. I do not want to run proguard on debug build as it makes debugging hard. I was wondering if there is a way to resolve this? One option I am considering is to build a local guava.jar and defining that as a dependency instead of pulling it from maven central. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It's not terrible to run ProGuard on debug builds - it will help you catch any ProGuard configuration errors early, rather than trying to track them all down in your release build.

Comment: Running proguard everytime in debug builds will waste a lot of time. Can you check the method counts for all the libraries you are using? Are you using stripped down versions of google play services or not?

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav, I am using stripped versions of google play services, right now guava is the biggest offender with 14K+ methods alone.

Comment: Can you exclude some packages from the guava lib, by using the 'exclude <package> in the gradle dependencies.

Comment: I inspected the dependencies and found that I they are mostly using "common.collect.", package, but stuff there have references to others. For now I am able to use jarjar to build a jar with classes in that package.

Answer (score 1):

Latest Android build tools support MultiDex option. This allows to build apps with over 65k methods. Just follow the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

Also you can enable automatic resource shrinking alongside with ProGuard:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
}﻿
```

Comment: I should have been more clear. this issue is for non proguarded debug builds. If I run proguard I dot hit the limit however I do not want to run proguard on debug varient

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Maybe you can use MultiDex in debug builds only.

Comment: Naively including gigantic libraries makes downloads, installs, and startup times longer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official doc of Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingProGuardWithGuava), you can use the following:

```
-injars path/to/myapplication.jar
-injars lib/guava-r07.jar
-libraryjars lib/jsr305.jar
-outjars myapplication-dist.jar

-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue

-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

This will keep your methods with the same name without obfuscating. Meaning that you can still debug properly with all the appropriate names written as is.

Comment: So how would you set this up for your debug build such that this only applies to guava jar only? I am already using proguard for release build and that works.

Comment: I did find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559723/is-it-possible-to-use-proguard-in-debug-mode but this still makes it hard to debug