# Minify breaking the debugger in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to enable minify to get around the 64k method limit. But now the debugger does not seem to work. When I put a breakpoint anywhere in the app, it says "No executable code found at line " and the code doesn't stop at the breakpoint.

How can I use the debugger without getting rid of the libraries I'm using?

Comment: add `debuggable true` . You can read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559723/is-it-possible-to-use-proguard-in-debug-mode

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya that didn't work.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I don't see anything in that link that helps me. I'm surprised there's not a standard way to get around this problem.